# Search function on site profile to find old questions or answer you wrote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I have been decently active on Stack Overflow for some time now and I have started to notice that I am finding questions that I know I have already answered in the past. I am wanting to find some of my older questions/answer that relate to the OP's problem and skimming through my history is a very tedious process.

Would it be possible to add a search feature on the questions/answer section of ones profile to make it easier to hunt down old post? Something that can search not just the titles but also the content of the post? This would allow me to link duplicates easier and find code I have already written for complex issues instead of having to write code from scratch on something I know I have answered before.

Update:

It has been pointed out that  [Stack Overflow Search - Now 61% Less Crappy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/29/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) has some useful search features that would help with my needs. That said I still think a search bar here would be useful. Maybe as a filter. From a user standpoint it would act like a simple filter for post related to your profile. Type something you are looking for and a filtered list of your history would be displayed below.

I would like to know others thoughts on this idea.

I was thinking something like this would be a good addition.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, type `user:me` before the search string. Additionally, if you know it’s an *answer* you wrote, add `is:a`. Similarly `is:q` for questions.

Comment: @DanBron where do you type this? The search field in the image above I added as a visual of what I would like to see. Are you saying to just search user:me in the normal search bar? And I am not fully sure what the `is:a` part. Can you add some more context to that.

Comment: Yes, the normal search bar. Say `code of conduct user:me is:a` for any answer you wrote on that site containing the three words (in any order, anywhere in the post) “of”, ”conduct”, “code”. If you want the exact string, enclose it in quotes.

Comment: @DanBron oh... That is useful to know thank you. I was not aware of this special search parameters. I guess that could work for me. I still think it would be a matter of convince to have this search bar on the profile. But I will start using what you provided. I am sure it will do the trick.

Comment: @DanBron looks like this is a recent addition to the search function. Didn't realize they added this. [Stack Overflow Search - Now 61% Less Crappy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/29/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)

Comment: You can do that in the SE iOS app, if it helps, though the app has been implicitly deprecated in favor of the mobile / responsive site :/ There is a new, supported app specifically for SO, but I don’t know if it has this desire or not.

Comment: See the link I posted above. This search operator (and the blog you just linked to) has been available since 2009 (9+ years ago). There are other search operators too, like `closed:1` and such, but I don’t have the link to the documentation on it handy right now.

Comment: @DanBron oh my bad. I was going of the date of the post that said it was "now posible" on the Q/A you linked.

Comment: I see. That answer has two dates on it: ‘09, when it was originally *posted*, and ‘17, when it was *last edited* (by a different user). I can see how that would be confusing.

Comment: @DanBron A link in help center where some of the advanced search operators are listed is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching And they can be displayed also if after [searching for something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=) you click on "Advanced Search Tips".